# Does Espresso work with ImageButton?

Tags: android, android-espresso

I have been working with test cases to perform a click on an ImageButton, but I always got the same exception:

`Action will not be performed because the target view does not match one or more of the following constraints:
is displayed on the screen to the user
Target view: "ImageButton{id=2131296372,res-name=create_an_account,..`

On the other hand, it works with a Button. This is the code:

`Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.create_an_account)).perform(ViewActions.onClick());`

Gradle:`com.jakewharton.espresso:espresso:1.1-r4-patched`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the button is visible on the screen.

If the button is covered by soft keyboard or is off-screen (for example, you're using ScrollView), you must first assure that the button is visible.

If the button is below keyboard - hide the keyboard.
If the button is off-screen - scroll down to make the button visible.

Same as the user cannot click invisible buttons - Espresso cannot too.

Comment: Yeah, It's visible: `<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/create_an_account"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
android:onClick="createAccount"
android:src="@drawable/create_an_account"
android:visibility="visible"/>`

Comment: Is it really visible on the screen at the moment of click? 

This error message tells it is not:

`view does not match one or more of the following constraints: is displayed on the screen to the user`

Comment: The problem is that the execution of the code is done before the emulator or device opens the application. It's a "machete" to write a sleep time. In theory, Espresso would should wait that view is loaded completely.

Answer (score -1):

The trick to set a sleep time in setup method before it executes the test methods.

`

```
public void setUp(){
   super.setUp();
   try {
          Thread.sleep(1000);             
   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
   }
 }
```

`